# How can calculate $J^\pi$?

Tags: angular-momentum, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, parity

According to the shell model the spin and parity of $^{89}_{38}$Sr is (7/2)$^+$, but the actual value is (5/2)$^+$ and also other elements   their $J^π$ does not correspond to the shell model expectations - e.g.  $^{47}_{22}$Ti , $^{55}_{25}$Mn , $^{75}_{33}$As , $^{61}_{28}$Ni.  Why?  How is $J^\pi$ calculated?

Comment: Please see how to format your text.

Comment: @T.Auerrac - you can remove your downvote, it is corrected now.

Comment: @jaromrax, it was not mine.

Comment: @T.Auerrac - I am sorry. any response from C R BAL?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you present - in the first place - $^{89}_{38}Sr_{51}$. 
You probably expect that the even number of 38 protons couple to the spin $0$ and there is one neutron above the magic shell $50$. It quite probably sits in $g_{7/2}$ orbital.

All this is a quite correct prediction. But look more closely to protons - they are just in the middle between $28$ and $50$ magic shells.

[image]

This diagram is based on simple Saxon-Woods well with parameters that show what we know from neiborhood of magic numbers. So it may be fine around closed shells.

If protons or neutrons or both depart from the magicity, you get lot of correlations and nuclei get deformed. One way would be to try to modify Saxon-Woods to deformed potential, the other would be to properly treat all the correlations within the shell model. Both things are trying to do the same - depart from the most simple picture.

Look at this picture - state of the art calculation published in Nature. You can find a bit different ordering as a function of (some) deformation for near nuclei. And $d_{5/2}$ shell is here lower than $g_{7/2}$

[image]

The last thing - look at http://www.iosrjournals.org/iosr-jap/papers/Vol3-issue4/G0345259.pdf?id=3341  where you can find this $(\pi d_{5/2})^{1}$ proton.

[image]

Other cases may differ. There can be a coupling to $2^+$ neutron configuration, that will become energetically more favored. There could be cross shell $\hbar\omega$ excitations that come down and compete with normal configurations.

And sorry to say, dont insist also on validity at magic numbers, they can disappear far from stability.